# error in text to speech code

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am following this tutorial for text to speech implementation in my app

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/

The speech is striked. please refer to the image below

After adding the code

[After editing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOHqr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the below liine of code:-

```
TextToSpeech textSpeach = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

**Change To**

```
   TextToSpeech textSpeach = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

            }
        });
```

***Reason of Problem*** :- You are passing the context `this` in both the parameter of `TextToSpeech` therefore this problem occurred, second this is the listner of the `TextToSpeech`

Comment: @BhanuSri declare the TextToSpeech t1 above the onCreate method  and than inside the oncreate use this t1 = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() ...

Comment: I have tried urs code..M not getting any error in it..Please look in the image http://tinypic.com/r/2mgmao4/9

Comment: Even in your image speak is striked

Comment: t1.speak is striked

Comment: It is not stricked..It is deprecated...U can use it..there is no problem in it

Comment: I have run the code in emmulator. I didnt hear any sound

Comment: Look this tutorilas https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm   http://www.javatpoint.com/android-texttospeech-tutorial   http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/02/android-text-to-speech-tts.html